# Add a sign to number, except for 0, using sprintf

Tags: r, printf

With `sprintf`, `"%+d"` prints number with sign:

```
sprintf("%+d",-2:2)
[1] "-2" "-1" "+0" "+1" "+2"
```

Is there an argument of `sprintf` to automatically escape 0 and get the following?

```
[1] "-2" "-1" "0" "+1" "+2"
```

Comment: In one call?  Because you can do `s <- sprintf("%+d",-2:2); s[s == "+0"] <- "0"; s`

Comment: I was wondering whether I was missing an option of `sprintf`. Of course, your solution works.

Comment: @RichardScriven - that may be one line, but it's multiple calls.

Comment: @thelatemail I know.  I wasn't meaning that it was a one-liner. I was asking OP if he wanted the `sprintf` as one call, then making my suggestion afterward.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a translation of how I would do this in C.  Print a leading `+` for positive values, and rely on default behavior for nonpositives:

```
x <- -2:2
sprintf("%s%d", ifelse(x>0,"+",""), x)
## [1] "-2" "-1" "0"  "+1" "+2"
```

Comment: Or `ifelse(x == 0, 0, sprintf("%+d",x) )` - yep.

Comment: One-liner with `sprintf("%s%d", ifelse((x <- -2:2) > 0,"+",""), x)`

Answer (score 2):

You could try removing the + afterwards with a gsub

```
 gsub("^\\+0$","0",sprintf("%+d",-2:2))
 [1] "-2" "-1" "0"  "+1" "+2"
```

Comment: A `"[+]0"` regex might be a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this would be

```
> s <- sprintf("%+d",-2:2)
> s[s == "+0"] <- 0
> s
# [1] "-2" "-1" "0"  "+1" "+2"
```

**Update:** I've also discovered you can do this...

```
> sprintf(c(rep("%d", 3), rep("%+d", 2)), -2:2)
# [1] "-2" "-1" "0"  "+1" "+2"
```

This one requires a specific number of `"%d"`s, but those could easily be calculated/inserted into the `rep` calls for use on other vectors.  It also benchmarked the fastest of all four current answers.

Answer (score 1):

Another gsub command which uses positive lookahead.

```
> gsub("[+](?=0)", "", sprintf("%+d",-2:2), perl=T)
[1] "-2" "-1" "0"  "+1" "+2"
```

In regex , lookaheads are used for condition checking purpose. `[+](?=0)` would match the symbol `+` only if it is followed by `0`. Replacing the matched `+` with empty string would turn `+0` to `0`

Comment: through negative lookahead `gsub("[+](?![^0])", "", sprintf("%+d",-2:2), perl=T)`